# Autowired.. more than one?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am using

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.package.dao"/> (Spring 3)
```

and in my controllers with **@Autowired** will retrieve automatically the DAO I need. That's perfect and works.
The problem is when I need more than one DAO manager.
How can I do?
I tried with **@Qualifier** but I am not sure about the name of the dao-manager. className doesn't work

someone can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any other xml configuration?  Or are all of your beans specified using annotations?

Comment: The qualifier value is the ID of the target bean.  That's up to you.

Comment: All my beans are specified using annotations, why?

Comment: @skaffman: Yes but using the component-scan I haven't to set the id anywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See in the [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers):

> @Autowired is fundamentally about type-driven injection with optional semantic qualifiers. This means that qualifier values, even when using the bean name fallback, always have narrowing semantics within the set of type matches; they do not semantically express a reference to a unique bean id
>
> ...
>
> If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not primarily use @Autowired - even if is technically capable of referring to a bean name through @Qualifier values. Instead, prefer the JSR-250 @Resource annotation which is semantically defined to identify a specific target component by its unique name, with the declared type being irrelevant for the matching process.

Use @Resource instead, see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-resource-annotation).